# What is a template?

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes

Regarding LaTeX I understand terms such as `class`, `package`, and so on but I don't understand the meaning of `template` as used by many questioners. Is it what is traditionally called a `package` or `class` or is it an example of a complete TeX document where the user edits the textual content, or ...?

Comment: Regarding what many unexperienced (and lazy ones, as well) users demand they understand by a `template` the 'working' document where they just change some minor things and everything should be out of the box.

Comment: https://twitter.com/templateGundar/status/634773854217478144

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion This question even came up in Barbara's column, asking for any help on defining the topic.

Comment: *Can i have template for this table please?*, *template for signature on titlepage* I actually came across those went i had a look at the questions tagged template.

Comment: If anybody wants to hear the ramblings of a mad man, just give me a ping and i add an answer.

Comment: Thanks for asking that question, just so we have it around. It seems like a lot of newcomers just want the equivalent of what people use as word processor templates (i.e. a document that contains all of the formatting you may need and dummy content as filler, then you just copy-paste and edit). Clearly, they have never been told about separating form and content and they just want to use TeX because someone told them it was fancy.

Comment: I've added an answer. The language is aimed at anyone who might read it, clearly not directly to you, Peter.

Answer (score 48):

As one of the resident linguists here, I'd like to add my two cents to this discussion.

First off, language meanings aren't carved in stone (or in dictionaries), but are essentially determined by language use.  And although there are some experienced LaTeX users on the site who would like to prescribe a particular meaning to the term, this is fundamentally a losing battle. So we need to look at (i) the people who tend to use the term (new users, mainly) and (ii) the contexts in which they seem to use the term.

It's fairly clear that most new users think of a template as a TeX *document* which, upon the addition of some content, will produce a document *with particular formatting characteristics*, a document type, so to speak.  Although some users do seem to use it as roughly synonymous to 'document class' (e.g. *I'm using the `tufte-latex` template*).

This is partially where the confusion comes about when this term gets used with experienced users. We clearly distinguish between document *types* from *tokens* of a particular document type.  We implement this by means of a class or a package, of course (see [Customizing LaTeX - create a document class or a package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53388/2693) for some discussion on the distinction).

So often times *part* of the answer to a new user's request for a 'template' will lead to pointing them to a particular document class or package that helps to produce a document of the type they are requesting.  But I think users who make such requests expect more than just this. They expect also, a sample document using that class or package so that they can see how a full document would look like.  The sample document should have most of the basic elements but not much content.

I maintain a thesis class for my university. In addition to the class itself and the documentation, I also provide a commented 'template' which is a TeX document which uses the class and contains most of the basic elements needed.  This gets new users started on using the class quite quickly, and certainly make my life easier in providing support, since it fends off most basic user questions.

So a 'template' for most users is a TeX document (a token) that instantiates a particular *type* of document.

If we keep this in mind when answering questions, it might be helpful for everyone.

P.S. I don't think that characterizing users who request such documents as 'lazy' is helpful or even accurate.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that as other approaches to document preparation (most obviously word processors) lend themselves to a a 'take this document and modify it' approach to providing the 'standard' formatting, there is an obvious reason that 'templates' get promoted generally. (Such approaches also often rely on the document itself to supply/maintain the formatting.)

Comment: Excellent answer (I also maintain my org's `\documentclass` and "stencil" document to get them started)

Answer (score 35):

The term isn't used (in that sense) anywhere in latex itself.

It is usually means a small sample document that loads up some particular class and selection of packages and has some dummy text, so people can just start from that and edit rather than read enough documentation to build a new document from scratch.

Answer (score 16):

A **template** is a complete example code for example to write the formalias for the master thesis of a special university.  Then there are added special commands to insert author, etc. at the required place, fullfilling the given title page etc. of the special university.

The problem with template is that a lot of them are buggy ...

The template uses classes (for example the class `thesis.cls`), which defines the layout of the paper and if needed special packages to add special funtions to the paper.

Other example: `moderncv.cls` is a class, including a template `example.tex` to create an cv.

Answer (score 10):

That very same question has been asked before by [Barbara Beeton in TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-3/tb114beet.pdf)

That question is impossible to answer though, because the term
*template* is not defined for LaTeX.

Let's take a look from different perspectives.

### Why is someone searching for a template?

Almost all users using that term want a base to start
with. A mould to pour in content.
An example to write a letter, or a thesis, a table with colored
rows  or something else and customize it to suit the requirements.

> I am just working on my template for my bachelor report and
> have problems with the headers.

> Can somebody share a template for this table?

Some users looking for a template are rather searching for a
special style.

> I like that template because it has colored headers.

> Does someone have a nice looking thesis template?

---

### Where can i get a template?

Let's have a look at where templates are available online.

- There are journal templates, often available at the journal
  homme page, often based on a special in-house
  class. The user opens a zip-file and finds a skeleton document
  along with some other needed files and can input his own text.
  Since a journal has a fixed layout, the style is fixed. Often so
  fix that it is merely impossible to alter the style.
- There are templates for theses or CVs (and other stuff), some
  on CTAN, some not. They differ in quality. When downloaded
  from a web site, usually a zip is provided, with a sample
  document and supporting files.  Some of those zip files are
  simple, merely pure examples of a normal latex file. Others are
  complex structures of directories, complex classes, [a bunch of
  stuff](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template). Usually, at
  least a bit of expertise goes into those documents.
- Overleaf and ShareLaTeX (and others) also provide templates.
  You can open a template and jhust start writing your journal
  article or thesis (it is advertised as such on one of the sites).
  Creating a template is as easy as pushing the *Publish as
  template* button, for every document you want. There is an
  incredible amount of templates around.

---

### Can template usage get messy?

Yes, for sure. It occasionally happens that a user found the
template of the *International Journal for Wombat Research
(IJWR)* nice for his homework assignment. Just the headers and
footers need to be fixed, and the margins. For a fixed  journal
layout, this isn't that easy.

Many templates are unmaintained. They often use old or
conflicting packages, some templates even cannot be compiled with
a current TeX Live<sup>1</sup>.

---

Some more thoughts can be found in [Template
Confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion).

---

### Conclusion

It is hard to put a label on the word *template* and one has to find out what is meant at every instance.
If someone is eager to discuss the template issue to find some
solutions or common terms, or even has some ideas, please write a mail to
tugboat@tug.org. You can also drop into our chat room.

---

<sup>1</sup> An Indian university provides a LaTeX
thesis template starting with `\documentstyle[epsfig]{article}`.

Comment: If somebody else thinks that [a bunch of stuff](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template) might be confusing for starters, give this comment an upvote.

Comment: By the way, if someone could add an answer to the following? Would be great, thanks. [Template/package for preparing notes for a blackboard talk?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237059)

Answer (score 8):

I've discovered that I'm a Grumpy Old Man (GOM) but I want to thank everyone who has answered and obviously put a lot of thought into it. As a GOM, and considering the other answers I'm now thinking of a Template as being example (La/TeX) code, preferably as a complete example document or as a code snippet for a particular task. I think that my summary word is `Example'. Putting on the GOM hat I feel that, given a Template, questioners should be able, perhaps with a little effort and reading of the documentation, to generate the document that they want.

I've just come across a website http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com which has many LaTeX examples. Perhaps this explains the popularity of `Template'.

Comment: no arguing, plus one.

Comment: @Johannes_B. Thank you. I'm hoping that this was for my anser but have a strong suspicion that it was admitting I'm a GOM.

Comment: Template = Example.

Comment: I am grumpy, though not old. I don't have a smartphone. Says all i guess.

Comment: The site you are mentioning in the edit is the reason for my grumpyness and insanity. Most of the examples are just bad examples.

Answer (score 3):

A good and common synonym for Template is Form. Templates aid in achieving sameness. Templates do that by setting or constraining visual or physical parameters of some productive process. Which aspects are duplicated by a template will vary by domain. For example, in a text document, the visual parameters of style are set by the template; but in the domain of manufacturing, a template is a physical object that either restricts movement parameters of material acted on by tools or restricts movement of tools acting on material. Across all domaines though, the point is efficient modes of achieving sameness in production.

Answer (score 2):

I think this particular usage of the word *template* comes from Microsoft Word users.  In that application, a template is essentially an example document with placeholder text and styling that can be customized to suit one's needs.  Word ships with several templates for letters, invoices, agendas, etc.

Templates can be pretty sophisticated with their own styles (in the MS Word sense) and even macros (I think).  I think the best analogue of this kind of template in the TeX universe is document class.

Comment: Documentclass along with an example document, so you have the placeholder text.