# Creating a template with an arguments mechanism

Tags: templates

I would like to create a template that would operate according to a default scheme but would offer some flexibility.

For example, (in the preamble?) there would be a question:

> TOC = [Y/N] %Default is Y, yes.

My questions are:

1. Am I actually looking to create a class? (rather than a template).
2. How is it done?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to define a significant number of new commands and/or environments, a package or class would be better. In general a package is more light-weight than a class, and would be preferable if the general setup of an existing class is sufficient, but you want to add or change some details. You can then use the option mechanism to specify the different Y/N answers, or even other parameters. For example by using the `xkeyval` package.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for a template engine. Unfortunately, the term *template* is very confusing for LaTeX users and used in many different ways.

Comment: Please also have a look at our questioin here: [What is a template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309614/what-is-a-template)

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Any news here? Have you tried a key-value-options package?

Comment: @TeXnician Since there was never any clarification and/or comments by the OP, what to do? As of now, the question is too-broad or opinion based. A possible answer would work based on pure assumptions.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/124577). As it stands this question is unclear and very broad.

Comment: @Johannes_B I've voted to close as too broad.