# obsolete lines in the following code

Tags: code

I am using the following .tex template borrowed from my colleague:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{palatino,float,subfigure,shadow,fancybox,amsfonts,appendix}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\pagestyle{fancy} \makeindex %\authorindex

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.1pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{{\rightmark}}} \fancyfoot{}
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\date{\today}
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000

\newcommand*\chancery{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{relsize}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,graphicx,amsxtra, setspace}

\usepackage{type1cm,eso-pic}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
                {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}%
        }{0.5ex}}%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\parskip 1ex

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}


\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\mainidx}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\boldidx}[1]{{\bf #1}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
        \mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
    \ht\z@=.9\ht\z@
    \widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}

\renewcommand{\d}{\/\mathrm{d}\/}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}


\def\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \cleardoublepage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\}
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}


\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat�s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat�s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat�s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=green           % color of external links
}


\newcommand {\apgt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel>\over\sim$}}\ }
\newcommand {\aplt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel<\over\sim$}}\ }

\makeatletter
\def\myfnt{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \doublespace
    \include{Title} 
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}1
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage
    
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % organisational level that receives a numbers
    \tableofcontents
    
    \newpage
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \include{Preliminaries}
    \include{chapter2}
    \include{chapter3}
    \include{chapter4}
    \include{chapter5}
    \include{chapter6}
    
    
    %The style you want to use for references.
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}\chapter*{Publications arising out of the PhD
        thesis\hfill} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications arising
        out of the PhD thesis}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [{[1]}]  
    \end{enumerate}
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \bigskip{}
    \vspace{1cm} \cleardoublepage
    
    
    
    \bibliography{references}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    
    
    \singlespace
    \printindex %\printauthorindex
\end{document}
```

Can some one help me to remove the obsolete commands in the file (commands which are present and don't serve any purpose).

Comment: Nobody knows what `\include{chapter2}` or `\include{chapter3}` contains. So how should we know if you load an unnecessary package.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports#Can_I_use_the_template_of_a_friend_or_one_I_found_online?

Comment: A good start would be stop loading  packages more than once. Surely you can do this on your own. If you need an example of a package that's loaded more than once, do look around for `graphicx` -- why on earth do you load it *three times*? Once you're done with that purge, you could start thinking about which packages aren't needed at all for your document.

Comment: @Mico You are right :) I am doing that now :)

Comment: @Mico I edited. Now every package shows up only once.

Comment: @Roland Are there anything else you find to be obsolete other than \include{chapter}?

Comment: The next step, as noted in my earlier message, is to check whether your document really needs that many packages. You should also ask yourself if you need both `graphics` and `graphicx` (hint: you don't; keep only the latter) and both `color` and `xcolor` (hint: you don't; keep the latter). Does your document really feature nine [!] separate theorem-like environments?

Comment: @Mico I like the style you write your comments :D  "Does your document really feature nine [!] separate theorem-like environments?" I use almost all, theorem, lemma, proposition, corollary, definition, example, remark.. Is 7 also too much? Is there a way to write this in a better way? I edited the code and removed 2 theorem-like environments

Comment: Obsolete is TeX engine you are using too. It seems (from \usepackage{inputenc} and from pzcr font) that you are using 8-bit pdftex. But now, we have Unicode luatex or xetex.

Comment: [Guide for creating your own template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448810/11604)

Comment: @wipet so how do I change to the new version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your document preamble is a real mess and I think it's useful to give some guidelines.

- `a4wide` has been deprecated for more than 20 years
- `epsfig` only exists for compatibility with two decade old document
- `palatino` has been deprecated for more than 20 years (use `mathpazo` or `newpxtext,newpxmath`)
- `subfigure` is deprecated
- `float` is unlikely to be useful (its `[H]` option for floats isn't useful)
- `type1cm` is obsolete
- DON'T use `\def`
- Why so many braces in the settings for `fancyhdr`?
- `\it` and `\bf` have been deprecated for a quarter of a century
- `\renewcommand\d{...}` is very dangerous, don't do it; I suggest `\dd`

Next, group packages according to their job. It will be easier to check for duplications and maybe to solve little incompatibilities by moving them around.

Reserve a section to general settings, such as defining page styles to be used later.

Place document specific new commands in a dedicated section.

A final section for document specific settings, such as line spacing, `\parskip` and so on. By the way, a nonzero `\parskip` together with `\doublespacing` will produce ***very*** wide white stripes.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

%%% Packages
% 1. fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for Computer Modern (comment if using the next line)
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % for Palatino
%\usepackage{upgreek} % do you need it?
%\usepackage{charter} % it has no support for math
%\usepackage{relsize} % do you need it?

% 2. Math
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % loaded by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

% 3. Graphics and special effects
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{shadow}% do you need it?
\usepackage{fancybox}% do you need it?
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% 4. Document formatting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% 5. Utilities
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point

% 6. Cross references and hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}


%%% General settings
% 1. fancyhdr
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.1pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

% 2. stackengine
\stackMath

% 3. hyperref
\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat�s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat�s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat�s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=green           % color of external links
}

%%% Personal commands
\newcommand*\chancery{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}

\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
                {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}%
        }{0.5ex}}%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newcommand{\mainidx}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\boldidx}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
        \mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
    \ht\z@=.9\ht\z@
    \widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand {\apgt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel>\over\sim$}}\ }
\newcommand {\aplt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel<\over\sim$}}\ }


\newcommand\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \cleardoublepage}
\newcommand{\addsymbol}{}% for safety
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\}
\newcommand\newnot[1]{\label{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myfnt{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother

%%% Last minute settings

\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeindex
%\authorindex

\doublespacing
\linespread{1.1}
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.1ex}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % organisational level that receives a numbers

%\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\include{Title} 

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
    
\tableofcontents
    
\include{Preliminaries}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
    
    
\chapter*{Publications arising out of the PhD
        thesis\hfill} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications arising
        out of the PhD thesis}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item [{[1]}]  
\end{enumerate}
    
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage
\singlespacing
\printindex %\printauthorindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! (+1). Does `mathtools` load `amsmath`?

Comment: This is giving error to me ... "Illegal parameter number in definition of \newnot. \newcommand\newnot#" "Missing \begin{document}. \newcommand\newnot#1" "Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \newcommand\newnot#1{\label{#1}" "Undefined control sequence. \counterwithin" "Missing \begin{document}. \counterwithin{e"

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sorry, I removed `\def` but didn't fix the parameter text. Fixed now.

Comment: @egreg It still says "Undefined control sequence. \counterwithin"

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You have a very old LaTeX distribution, probably. Substitute with `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`.

Comment: how do I change the latex distribution? with "\numberwithin{equation}{section}" it is coming correctly. not showing any error

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - Since you haven't told us yet which TeX distribution (and which vintage) you employ, it's well-nigh impossible to give you sensible advice. Please do reveal which TeX distribution (MikTeX? TeXLive? something else?) you employ and when it was last updated.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It depends on what operating system you're running and what TeX distribution

Comment: running "pdflatex --version" in terminal I got pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) kpathsea version 6.2.3 Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING and the pdfTeX source. Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
 Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34 Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11 Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 6):

Let me take the following stab at addressing the substance of your question.

- *Don't load packages more than once.* Absolutely nothing good will come of it. Making sure that any package is loaded only once should be fairly easy to accomplish, right?
- Don't load both `color` and `xcolor`, or both `graphics` and `graphicx`. Hint: work with `xcolor` and `graphicx`.
- Don't define more theorem-like environments than you really need.
- Obsolete and deprecated packages: It takes a bit more experience to figure out which packages belong in this group. Start by *not* loading `subfigure` and `epsfig`. You also load several text font packages whose code gets clobbered later on, when additional font packages get loaded. E.g., what are you trying to accomplish by loading `palatino`, `charter`, and `type1cm`?
- Your document's preamble is a *mess* in part because no grouping of commands by theme or purpose seems to have been performed. Suggestion: Immediately after loading a package, execute the instructions from that package you deem necessary. E.g., after loading `fancyhdr`, don't load several more packages, then run `\pagestyle{fancy}`, then run `\makeidx`, and then (re)define the `fancy` page parameters. Is it really that hard to apply some grouping?
- Don't load packages by hand if they're loaded automatically by other packages. E.g., `amsfonts` is loaded by `amssymb`, `amsmath` is loaded by `mathtools`, etc.
- Some packages, and the `hyperref` package in particular, are loaded too early. An excellent rule of thumb is to load `hyperref` *last*. Do you really set `pdftitle={My title}`, `pdfproducer={Producer}`, etc? Put differently, why aren't you entering real information.
- Code that's either redundant, superfluous, or plain bad. Since you employ the `book` document class, I can see no valid reason for executing `\pagenumbering{roman}` *in the preamble*. Instead, you should be executing `\frontmatter` immediately after `\begin{document}` and `\mainmatter` at, you guessed it, the start of the main part of the document. That will also spare you from having to type `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\setcounter{page}{1}`. I also don't understand the purpose of the multitude of `\clearpage` and `\newpage` instructions.
- Code that's absolutely not needed. (I guess that would make it "super-redundant", right?) That's something I cannot judge fully since I have no knowledge of the contents of the document. I'd cycle through each package, one at a time: don't load a package and recompile the document twice. If the document compiles fine, that particular package wasn't needed.

If you manage to wade through all of these steps, your document will likely be a lot more streamlined too.

Comment: I disagree with your fifth bullet: first load all packages, which makes easier to check du-lications or to move them around to avoid clashes; then dedicate a section of the preamble to settings specific to each package; then personal commands; finally, settings specific to the document that might be subject to changes at the last minute (double spacing, page style, and so on, such as settings to `\clubpenalty`).

Comment: I have made all changes you suggested except bullet 5,7 (which I do not understand what it means).. I do not understand "I also don't understand the purpose of the multitude of \clearpage and \newpage instructions."

Comment: @egreg -- I guess you're proposing a different approach to organizing the commands in the preamble -- load all packages first, then a sequence of commands that make use of the packages' capabilities, and so on. The main thing, then, is to apply *some kind of grouping*. Almost any approach to grouping must be better than the current situation...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - After `%The style you want to use for references`, there's `\newpage`, `\clearpage`, and `\cleardoublepage`; at least some of those instructions must be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{float,subfigure,shadow,fancybox,appendix}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\pagestyle{fancy} \makeindex %\authorindex

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.1pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{{\rightmark}}} \fancyfoot{}
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}
\date{\today}
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000

\newcommand*\chancery{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{relsize}


\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,graphicx,amsxtra, setspace}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
                {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}%
        }{0.5ex}}%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\parskip 1ex

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}


\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\mainidx}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\boldidx}[1]{{\bf #1}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
        \mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
    \ht\z@=.9\ht\z@
    \widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}

\renewcommand{\d}{\/\mathrm{d}\/}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}


\def\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \cleardoublepage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\}
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}


\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat�s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat�s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat�s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=green           % color of external links
}


\newcommand {\apgt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel>\over\sim$}}\ }
\newcommand {\aplt} {\ {\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\buildrel<\over\sim$}}\ }

\makeatletter
\def\myfnt{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \doublespace
    \include{Title} 
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage
    
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % organisational level that receives a numbers
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \newpage
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \include{Preliminaries}
    \include{chapter2}
    \include{chapter3}
    \include{chapter4}
    \include{chapter5}
    \include{chapter6}
    
    
    %The style you want to use for references.
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}\chapter*{Publications arising out of the PhD
        thesis\hfill} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications arising
        out of the PhD thesis}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [{[1]}]  
    \end{enumerate}
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \bigskip{}
    \vspace{1cm} \cleardoublepage
 
    \bibliography{references}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    
    
    \singlespace
    \printindex %\printauthorindex
\end{document}
```

This is the code I end up with after doing what Mico suggested.

Comment: Umm, I thought I recommended not loading the `subfigure` package. If your document does contain sub-figures and -tables, do look into using either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package. I would also defer loading the `hyperref` package until just before `\hypersetup`.